# Disable Ionic keyboard when focus on input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard

I'm using v1 Ionic, specifically for android 4.4.2. I'm trying to disable keyboard when focused on input field, i dont want to make input read-only or disabled, i tried every solution from this site, none is working, is there anyone with hidden trick? it would be helpful

Comment: You tried which solution (where is the code)? From which site?

Comment: what 'this' site means?
tryed with cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close(), from plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Android device with a physical keyboard, for example Android Barcode Scanner, you can do this using [Null Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wparam.nullkeyboard&hl=en) app.

After you've installed the application go to the **Settings** - **Language & input** - check **Null keyboard** and choose **input method**: **Hardware**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by add `disabled` attribute to your input tag, for example

```
<input type="text" name="name" disabled>
```

This might change background color of input, but you can change that using css. Like

```
input[disabled], select[disabled], textarea[disabled], input[readonly]:not(.cloned-text-input), textarea[readonly]:not(.cloned-text-input), select[readonly] {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me